# Como receber um arquivo PDF em Django e salvar em um diretório?

Tags: html, python, django, pdf

Recebo um arquivo pelo html usando type="file".

```
<form action="/docs/enviado/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="file" accept="pdf" name = "projeto"/><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Mas não consigo salvar usando o python, tentei assim mas não deu certo:

```
projeto = request.POST.get('projeto')
projeto.save
```

E assim:

```
projeto = request.FILES["projeto"]
projeto.save
```

Só preciso receber o arquivo pdf e salvar no diretório que já está.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu form

```
<form action="/docs/enviado/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

No seu campo no model:

```
meuarquivo = models.FileField(upload_to='meusarquivos/')
```

Na sua view

```
form = MeuForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Então, sem jeito de fazer sem usar models?

Comment: Da pra fazer sem usar o model sim. Você só tem que ver o que você fará com o arquivo e como você irá salvar no diretório.